# Answer preview in MSE not appearing

Tags: support, editing, markdown-preview

Whenever I am going to write an answer or edit someone's post, I am not able to see its preview under the answer writing section in MSE. Why is this happening?

[image: MSE image]

Comment: I think you are using Android phone (blue colour  never  show in laptop). Generally in laptop  this  problem  will not occur.Try  to used laptop  instead of mobile phone

Comment: @jasmine2 no I am using desktop

Answer (score 7):

This is the (deprecated) [mobile web](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mobile-web/info) version of the site; it does not have a preview when editing posts.

To switch back to the full version, click the 'full site' link in the footer. It seems you have a large enough screen to not need using the mobile web version.

Comment: I've hated the mobile web version back when I had an iPhone 4 with its (relatively) tiny screen. And yet, I wrote many an answers on the full version of the site from my phone.

Comment: I use desktop. The image was taken from mobile and cropped. Mobile is quite notorious for such usage.

Comment: odd that 'mobile' is depreciated when there is still a link to it in the footer from the 'full site'!